# register_shutdown_function() still outputs original error message

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the built in php shutdown_function with a custom one.

It works perfectly, however, it still outputs the original error (built in error) above my new error message.

```
  <?php
  function shutdown_output() {
      $error = error_get_last();
      if($error !== NULL) {
          echo "ERROR";
          exit();
      } else {
          echo "NO ERROR";
      }
  }

  // Set the error reporting:
  register_shutdown_function('shutdown_output');

  // test.php does not exist, just here to get a critical error
  require_once("test.php");

  ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not surprised if you haven't turned off PHP's own error reporting. [`error_reporting(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: You have to also set `error_reporting(0);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` for this not to output the original error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, the use of `register_shutdown_function` is not going to override built-in error handling (the same way that `set_error_handler` doesn't either).

If you don't want to see the original message, disable the output of them in your `php.ini` using `display_errors = 0`. Or on the fly in your script using `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`.

Comment: "the same way that `set_error_handler` doesn't either": but the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) says: "the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by `error_types` unless the callback function returns `FALSE`"?

Comment: @AlvinWong Perhaps what I said was misleading, `set_error_handler` only handles `E_USER_*` (and a couple other) errors, in other cases the default handler would be used.